# How change Windows 7 so applications launch Thunderbird instead of Outlook?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

I have a number of applications (e.g. GoToMeeing) which open up an e-mail which is ready to write.
However, they always open Outlook instead of the e-mail client that I use: Thunderbird.

**Where is the config file / setting in Windows7 so applications open Thunderbird by default instead of Outlook?**

## Addendum

Thunderbird is not in my "list of standard programs":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Click the Start Menu and select `Default Programs` from the right
  hand menu column.
- From there, click `Default Program` again.
- Highlight Thunderbird from the list that gets built and click Choose
  defaults for this program.
- Finally, select the mail option from the
  list of actions and click Save.

If the program is not in the list of possible, try this:

- Back up one screen to the `Default programs` page
- Select `Associate a file type or protocol with a program`
- Scroll to the very bottom of the list to the protocol section
- Select the program you want to use or Browse to find Thunderbird.

Comment: I got that far, but Thundbird (or Outlook for that matter) is not in my list of standard programs (screenshot posted above in question). How can I add them to this list?

Comment: I added instructions for adding programs to the list